# How do i get a character from getc and put it into my array?

Tags: assembly, arm

So i have an array of character counts, indexed by the character number from the ascii table up to 255.

Now i have a file in that i read all done, and a loop through it, but I want to increment the character count in my array for the character i read in. I can't seem to figure out how to do this...

Here is my code (fully commented):

```
.global main
.global printf
.global .fopen
.global .fclose
.global getc

main:
    ; Open File
    PUSH {R1} ; Push address of R1 onto stack
    LDR R0, [R1, #0x04] ; Get argv[1] from stack to R0
    LDR R1, =r ; Load address of file open format (read)
    BL fopen ; Open file
    LDR R1, =fin ; Load address of file in to R1
    STR R0, [R1] ; Store contents of R1 into R0

    ; Setup array
    LDR R4, =ch_array ; Array address
    MOV R3, #0 ; Array index

    BL loopFile
    BL printArray

@ Loop through the file
loopFile:
    LDR R1, =fin ; Load R1 with address of file in
    LDR R0, [R1] ; Load R0 with pointer? of R1
    BL getc ; Get next character from file into R0?
    CMP R0, #-1 ; Check for end of file
    BEQ endl ; Close file

    @ Write the storing in array code
    ; get index from character (getc)

    B loopFile ; Run loop again

@ Close th file
endl:
    LDR R1, =fin ; Load R1 with address of file in
    LDR R0, [R1] ; Load R0 with pointer? of R1
    BL fclose ; Close the file

printArray:
    /*
    CMP R2, #ARRAY_MAX ; while (i < ARRAY_MAX)
    BEQ _exit ; Exit if max
    @ print?
    ; Check if value of the array at index i (i = character number) is 0, if so then skip it
    ADD R2, #0x01 ; Add 1 to i
    B printArray ; Loop next iteration of array
    */

_exit:
    MOV R7, #1
    MOV R0, #0
    SWI 0

.data
    .equ ARRAY_MAX, 255
    ch_array:
        .rept ARRAY_MAX ;For all elements in array, repeat:
        .word 0x00 ;Initialize to 0
        .endr ;End repetition
    fin:   .word 0x00
    r:     .asciz "r"
    space: .word ' '
    nl:    .word '\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the base address is in `R4` and the ASCII code is in `R0`, what you want to do is increment the word in memory at address `R4 + R0*4` (the `*4` is necessary because each word is 4 bytes).

In thumb assembly that could be done like this:

```
LSL R0, R0, #2
LDR R1, [R4, R0]
ADD R1, R1, #1
STR R1, [R4, R0]
```

Comment: When you increment 1 to register R1, should that be R3 in my case?

Comment: No. It should be to the register into which you loaded the word at the given index in the array.

Comment: Oh okay then in that case it would be R1 like you wrote